# Error when installing postfix 18.04 LTS

Tags: dpkg, email, postfix

Haven't done much on this machine yet but when I try to install Postfix it does this to me. I am trying to build an email server for my Linux class.

root@mail:~# sudo apt-get install postfix -y

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  python3-netifaces

Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.

Suggested packages:
  procmail postfix-mysql postfix-pgsql postfix-ldap postfix-pcre postfix-lmdb postfix-sqlite sasl2-bin dovecot-common resolvconf postfix-cdb
  postfix-doc

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  postfix
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 140 not upgraded.

Need to get 1,147 kB of archives.

After this operation, 4,077 kB of additional disk space will be used.

Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 postfix amd64 3.3.0-1ubuntu0.2
  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/postfix/postfix_3.3.0-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Answer (score 0):

[How To Install and Configure Postfix on Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-on-ubuntu-18-04)  this answer from digitalocean